# Hidden city- baggage question- Intl arrival to US

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, hidden-city-ticketing

Bought a one way from Sao Paulo to Brussels on Delta with connections in ATL and JFK. Route is GRU-ATL-JFK-BRU. Plan is to get off in ATL as this ticket was signficantly cheaper than a straight GRU-ATL ticket. I will need to check a bag but since ATL is first port of entry, I'll be able to retreive and exit airport, correct?

Is there any scenario that the bags would go straight to JFK or BRU?

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken into account, that there is a chance that you (along with your bags) won't be passing through ATL but you're sent straight to JFK or BRU (flight is overbooked, cancelled, ...)

Comment: @Sabine:  To be fair, that's a risk with any hidden-city ticket, regardless of whether or not you're trying to reclaim a checked bag.

Comment: but barring a mishap the checked bag would end up in ATL? there is a direct GRU-JFK flight 30 minutes before the GRU-ATL leg, would they conceivably load the bag onto that plane thinking they are doing me a favor? but if i remained ticketed to ATL would they load the bag on another plane?

Answer (score 3):

If your bags are mishandled on the first flight and somehow don't make it on to the GRU-ATL plane with you, they would presumably be put on later flights to BRU by default.  Since Delta also flies from São Paulo to JFK, Orlando, and Detroit nonstop, it's possible that your delayed bags wouldn't even pass through ATL at all.

In this scenario, you *might* be able to convince the Delta baggage agents to deliver your delayed bags to ATL instead, but that might involve admitting to a Delta agent that you're using hidden-city ticketing.  I'm not sure I'd want to do that, personally;  but you might be less conflict-averse and/or rules-oriented than I am.